# Would it work to connect a 12V power adaptor to the power wires of a FireWire 400 (IEEE 1394a) cable?

Tags: power-supply, camera

I'd like to power my Phase One H20 digital camera back, but my macbook doesn t give enough juice. The firewire repeaters seem to be quite pricey. And I think all I need is to put 12V and >1.5A to the Vcc of the firewire cable, at least according to this article: https://www.phaseone.com/search/article.aspx?articleid=1858&languageid=1 I think my power adaptor (12V-2000mA) for my external HDD should work fine with it, or is there any risk of ruining my H20?

-Thanks

Comment: Risk to your camera. Risk to your laptop. Risk to data quality. Risk all round.

Comment: What kind of risk? How do the active hubs avoid it?

Comment: I know it can be done with USB: http://www.instructables.com/id/Adding-an-external-power-supply-to-a-cheap-USB-hub/

Comment: Instructables doesn't mean it can be done, nor that it is wise. Instructables just means someone equally unsensible tried it and had the luck of not messing something up. Active hubs avoid it, by being active hubs, designed by someone who knows the protocol, specs and actual EE, not wires kludged together by someone getting all their todo's from Instructables.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do they avoid it by being active hubs?

Comment: Open a wire, any wire. Open a hub, any hub. Count the number of chips and the amount of PCB tracework in each one of them. Compare and ponder.

Comment: I do not have access to any firewire hubs at the moment, but it seems like the piece for Mamiya Leaf digital back (another brand of medium format backs) is pretty simple: http://www.adorama.com/images/Large/mydctfw8sadl.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IEEE1394-2008](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4659233&filter=AND%28p_Publication_Number:4659231%29) says in section 9.4.1:

> The possibility of multiple sources requires that cable power sources be manufactured such that current from 
>   a node providing higher voltage does not flow into sources of lower output voltage.
>   […]
>   Cable power sources that supply a  minimum of 20 V shall identify themselves with
>   POWER_CLASS one, two, or three in their self-ID packet(s) and shall implement, for each of their ports, a
>   diode and current-limiting scheme whose behavior is equivalent to that illustrated by Figure 9-25.
>
> [image: Node power interface for POWER_CLASS one, two, or three]
>
> In addition, cable power sources shall provide over-voltage and short-circuit protection in compliance with
>   the limited power source requirements in Section 2.5 of IEC 60950. Implementations might utilize
>   impedance protection, such as polymer PTC devices, compliant with Table 2B of IEC 60950 or overcurrent
>   protection, such as a fuse, in compliance with Table 2C of that standard.

The 20 V requirement just ensures that at least 8 V are available even if ten intermediate devices in the chain drop some voltage; for a single device, 12 V would work just fine.

Never mind POWER_CLASS; it's often set wrong, and nobody reads it.